# Android get height of web view

Tags: java, android, view, webview

I need to get the height of my web view so I can programatically work out the top margin. I'm using the AddOnPreDraw method which works fine on phones, but as soon as I use it on a tablet it returns null.

```
ViewTreeObserver viewTreeObserver = topContent.getViewTreeObserver();

    viewTreeObserver.addOnPreDrawListener(new OnPreDrawListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onPreDraw() {
            int height = topContent.getMeasuredHeight();
            if (height != 0) {
                Log.d("Web View Height", "Continue Height: " + height);
                    RelativeLayout instructions = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.info_layout);
                    instructions.post(mAddTabletMargin);
            }
            topContent.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(
                    this);
            return false;
        }

    });
```

So quesiton one is why does it work on phones but not tablets?
and question 2 is there any other methods I could use to get the height of the webvie wonce it's been drawn?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way to perform this.

```
webView.post(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            webView.getHeight();
        }
    });
```

Comment: thats look perfect, the only thing is though, why does my way work on phones such as the nexus 5 and the samsung galaxy s4?

Comment: it's still not getting the height, It's running my onPreDraw method before the webviews are drawn only on the nexus 7!

Comment: thats not possible make sure you are running this method on UIthread

Comment: I figured out what the problem was, I was being pretty stupid really! I moved `topContent.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);` into the `if` statement and then the `onPreDraw` method kept looping until it got the height, then once I got the height, the `if` statement was executed which stopped the method from looping and I could then make all of the measurements I needed, Thanks for the help though dude.

Comment: I could maybe just change it to a while loop until it gets the height?